# Saint Petersburg: What happens when you upgrade a full warehouse?

Tags: saint-petersburg

In Saint Petersburg, if you own a warehouse you can hold an extra card in hand.  What happens if you have four cards in hand and then upgrade the warehouse?

- Do you keep the fourth card, but can't take another fourth in hand
  after you've played it?
- Do you discard one?
- Are you just not allowed to do the upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with your first option, **you keep the extra card but your hand limit goes back to normal**.

This is covered in [these rules](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=150) in the **special cards** description (which I think isn't part of the main rules book but is an extra rules reminder sheet):

> The player can have up to **4 cards in his hand**. If the player upgrades the warehouse, he need not immediately reduce his hand to 3 cards.